# Changing citation language in latex

Tags: latex, citations

I am trying to include citations APA style in my latex document which is written in dutch. However, the citations appear as

author e.a. (year)

instead of

author et al. (year)

The first is probably some translation, but in dutch is is very common to still use et al. How do I change the citations in text to et al.?

```
    \documentclass[dutch]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}   
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Refrences.bib}


\begin{document}
\begin{otherlanguage}{dutch}

Dit is een test. \cite{Schleigh2015}. \cite{Slater2015}

\bibliography{bibliography} 
\printbibliography

\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

output:

Dit is een test. Schleigh e.a., 2015. Slater e.a., 2015

Also, i just discoverd that apperently this apa style does not print an "&" when more than three authors are present. Instead in prints the word "and", which is not apa.

Author1, Author2 AND Author3

which should be:

Author1, Author2 & Author3

Comment: Can you make a [mre]?

Comment: \documentclass[dutch]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}   
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Refrences.bib}


\begin{document}
\begin{otherlanguage}{dutch}

Dit is een test. \cite{Schleigh2015}. \cite{Slater2015}

\bibliography{bibliography} 
\printbibliography

\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}

Comment: Please see [Using ampersand symbols (&) instead of the word “and” for bibliography style apa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28529/using-ampersand-symbols-instead-of-the-word-and-for-bibliography-style-apa)

Comment: @mspilsbury I am currently unsing overleaf, so I am not able to dowload and change that file

Comment: Please move the second part of your question into a separate post. Only one problem per question works best for a Q&A sites like Stackoverflow.

Comment: then you can see [Biblatex: Using “and” within textcite, “&” within parencite, “&” within bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359426/biblatex-using-and-within-textcite-within-parencite-within-bibliogr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily you use the biblatex package, this makes it easy to adjust the string:

```
\documentclass[dutch]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}   
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{dutch}{
  andothers        = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},
  andmore          = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},
}

\begin{document}

Dit is een test. \cite{aksin}. 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Some other comments about your code:

- `apa` styles requires the biber backend. With your attempt to use it with biblatex, you should have gotten an error messages telling you that. Please do not ignore error messages
- your are mixing syntaxes from two different bibliography tools. `\addbibresource{...}` and `\printbibliography` are correct syntax for biblatex.  `\bibliography{bibliography}` is not.
- with `\usepackage[dutch]{babel}` you already changed the main language of your document to dutch, `\begin{otherlanguage}{dutch}...\end{otherlanguage}` is not necessary